# Аналог [one-definition-rule] на ruSO

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Переводя вопрос с enSO, не нашёл подходящей замены для [one-definition-rule]. Существует ли она? Если нет, то нужна ли?

Upd: сам вопрос: [Когда следует использовать inline для функции/метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823755/197525).

Comment: @AK, он метку на вопрос спрашивает.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, у нас такой метки нет. И пока неясно, нужна ли она. Даже на enSO по ней всего 163 вопроса - это очень мало.